# React Intl - Single file for every component

Tags: reactjs

Is it possibile to have a specific translation file for every component istead of a unique big file?
I have organized specific component in subfolder and it will be good to have a specific translation file in the same folder.

Im actually import the big language file with this import command:

```
import { ENGLISH } from './locales/en';
```

Which is something like this:

```
export const ENGLISH = {
    lang: 'en',
    messages: {
        "test_message" : "Test Message",
    [...]
```

Than in constructor I set the state:

```
 locale : 'en',
 messages: ENGLISH.messages,
```

Than in render code:

```
<IntlProvider locale={this.state.locale} messages={this.state.messages}>
[...]
```

Thanks you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, it depends on how you want to organise your code. For example, just create translation files for every component. So instead of **'./locales/en'** do something like **'./locales/yourcomponent/en'** so this way you will have all the languages in one component folder.

So: **import ENGLISH from './locales/MyComponent/en';** and you export default instead of just export

Moreover you can create an index file in **./locales/MyComponent** where you import all your languages if you want and then export them from index so you can use it like **import { ENGLISH } from './locales/MyComponent'**.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but im missing a couple of things about your solution. First of all, I want to put my component tranlastion file in the same directory of the component jsx because I want the component to be stand-alone as much as possible.
Now. My App.jsx, which is the root app, has the IntlProvider tag that act for every children below.
So, how I can, in my component, use the base translation (inherited from above) and the specific component translation file (merging the dictionary)?

Comment: hey @RetroMime do you have a solution? I am kind of stuck on same problem

Comment: i think it is better to have one big file. because each time you add new folder to the project you have to comeback and import it in root translation, and it is one file translating to another locale file is much easier basically you have to worried about one single file. so less human mistake.

Answer (score 0):

This was asked a while ago but I have a possible solution. In my own project I have my translation files separated by routes and I import them into a main translation file that I pass to my `IntlProvider`.

```js
src
-- i18l
---- translations.js //main translation file
---- home.js
---- about.js
---- profile.js
-- app.js
```

I import each route translation file into my main translation file and put them into their respective objects using the spread operator.

*home.js*

```js
export const homeEn = {
    //translations here
}
export const homeFr = {
    //translations here
}
```

*translations.js*

```js
import { aboutEn, aboutFr } from "./about"
import { homeEn, homeFr } from "./home"
import { profileEn, profileFr } from "./profile"

export default ({
  "en": {
    //translations
    ...aboutEn,
    ...homeEn,
    ...profileEn
  },
  "fr": {
    //translations
    ...aboutFr,
    ...homeFr,
    ...profileFr
  }
})
```

I imagine you could do something similar where you import your translation files from your component into a main translation file.